# How to change ancestor's property with a trigger on template child

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have a combobox and I have templated its control template. Togglebutton is a part of the control template. Now when a event is raised on the togglebutton(ex: Checked), I want to change combobox property(ex:Foreground). How to do this? Can we do this using relativesource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Trigger` in the `ControlTemplate` and use the [`Trigger.SourceName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger.sourcename.aspx) property to specify the `ToggleButton` as the source of the trigger.

Example:

```
<ControlTemplate ... >
    <Grid ... >
        <!-- ... -->
        <ToggleButton x:Name="btnToggle" ... />
        <!-- ... -->
    </Grid>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger SourceName="btnToggle" Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Of course, this only applies to properties and not events, as you requested. However, there are many properties which can be used instead of the events, like the `IsChecked` property instead of the `Checked` event.

Comment: Appreciate your answer.However when it triggers I want the property of Combobox to be changed(like opacity or foreground) and not togglebutton's property. Is there anyway to refer the combobox from togglebutton?

Comment: Actually, I assumed that the above code would set the `ComboBox`'s `Foreground` to `Red` and not the `ToggleButton`'s. *Did you try the code?* Normally, if you do not specify a `TargetName` in the `Setter`, it is applied to the templated control, in this case the `ComboBox`. However, this might not be true if the `Trigger`'s `SourceName` property is used. But you should still give it a try if you did not do so yet!